# Extract dimensions from a string using PHP

Tags: php, string, extract

I want to extract the dimension from this given string.

```
$str = "enough for hitting practice. The dimension is 20'X10' *where";
```

I expect **20'X10'** as the result.

I tried with the following code to get the number before and after the string **'X**. But it is returning an empty array.

```
$regexForMinimumPattern ='/((?:\w+\W*){0,1})\'X\b((?:\W*\w+){0,1})/i';
preg_match_all ($regexForMinimumPattern, $str, $minimumPatternMatches);
print_r($minimumPatternMatches);
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the string always the same apart from the dimensions part?

Comment: nop.. The string may change.

Comment: Is it always in feet, and a whole number? If yes then I think `\d+'\h*X\h*\d+'` would be a stricter regex. If `1.75'X3.75'` or `1'9"X3'9"` would be valid you will need something looser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `\b` from your pattern (and append a `\'` in the end if you want the trailing quote):

```
$regexForMinimumPattern ='/((?:\w+\W*){0,1})\'X((?:\W*\w+){0,1})\'/i';
```

NB: `\b` is the [meta-character for word-boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), you don't need it here.

Comment: This results in  20'X10 instead of  20'X10'. Last quote is missing.

Comment: @fiddler..Thanks it is now returning what I have expected.

Comment: This is a rather loose pattern for the task.  `{0,1}` is more concisely written as `?`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the format of the string we want is 00'X00 :

```
$regexForMinimumPattern ='/[0-9]{1,2}\'X[0-9]{1,2}/i';
```

this gives you a result like

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 20'X10 ) )

Comment: I need it as 20'X10'

Comment: Then just add \' at the end. `/[0-9]{1,2}\'X[0-9]{1,2}\'/i`

Comment: well if you look at the pattern, just add another \' before /i

Comment: If the `x` is always suppose to be a capital take off the `i` modifier.

Comment: And if your string contains newline(s), you need to add `m` modifier (for multiline support)

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt Nope, the `m` is so `^` and `$` are treated as per line as opposed to the whole string.

Comment: This moment when you realize you used something for years for something else then what its supposed to be lol. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

So: can a simple `preg_replace()`do that? Perhaps...

```
<?php
    $str    = "enough for hitting practice. The dimension is 20'X10' *where";
    $dim    = preg_replace("#(.*?)(\d*?)(\.\d*)?(')(X)(\d*?)(\.\d*)?(')(.+)#i","$2$3$4$5$6$7", $str);
    var_dump($dim);     //<== YIELDS::: string '20'X10' (length=6)
```

You may try it out [Here](https://eval.in/625026).

Comment: That's a lot of capture groups, why not just one large capture group? Also the numbers probably shouldn't be optional a quoted `X` would match.